# Get value first line into the second line (Table) in ms access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created a spare list that have Part In and Part Out. As illustrate in image below.

[image]

As you can see there is Part In, Part Out and Stock Balance. Which when I enter the Part In value=1, the Stock balance value is equal to 1 and when I enter the Part Out value it will deduct the stock balance value. The problem is how to capture the Stock balance value from row 1 into row 2? The idea when entered new value Part In :

```
[Stock Balance row 2 = Stock Balance from row 1 + Part In]
```

I hope you understand my explanation and will help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't take into account the row number when talking about database tables as the order of data is irrelevant.  Is there a value in one of the fields that identifies the previous stock movement?  Afraid I can't see the image on this computer but I suspect the table could do with some changes if you have the balance on there as well - it may be better just to have three fields in the table - date/time of transaction, direction of transaction (in or out) and number of parts in transaction.  You can then add all the parts in, minus all the parts out and get the balance at any point in time

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook thanks Darren for your response. Appreciate it. Can you share any an example for transaction in/out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's too long for a comment I'll add this as an answer to flesh out my comment of

> it may be better just to have three fields in the table - date/time of
>   transaction, direction of transaction (in or out) and number of parts
>   in transaction. You can then add all the parts in, minus all the parts
>   out and get the balance at any point in time

Run the following VBA to create a table containing the three fields and add some sample data:

```
Sub Test()

    With DoCmd

        .SetWarnings False

        .RunSQL "CREATE TABLE Stock (" & _
            "Date_Time DateTime, Direction CHAR, Unit INTEGER)"

        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES(#2017/11/20 07:00:00#, 'In', 100)"
        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES(#2017/11/20 07:00:01#, 'Out', 5)"
        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES( #2017/11/20 07:00:02#, 'In', 3)"
        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES(#2017/11/20 07:00:05#, 'In', 2)"
        .RunSQL "INSERT INTO Stock VALUES(#2017/11/20 07:10:00#, 'Out', 15)"

        .SetWarnings True

    End With

End Sub
```

This SQL will give you a running total of the balance:

```
SELECT        T1.Date_Time
            , T1.Direction
            , T1.Unit
            , (
               SELECT   SUM(Unit)
               FROM     Stock
               WHERE    Direction='IN' AND Date_Time<=T1.Date_Time
               ) -
              NZ((
               SELECT   SUM(Unit)
               FROM     Stock
               WHERE    Direction='OUT' AND Date_Time<=T1.Date_Time
               ),0) AS Balance
FROM        Stock T1
```

This SQL will give the balance at a specific point in time:

```
SELECT      Date_Time AS TimeFrame
            , (
            SELECT  SUM(Unit) AS Stock_In
            FROM    Stock
            WHERE   Direction='In' AND Date_Time<=#2017/11/20  07:00:05#
              )  - 
            (
            SELECT  SUM(Unit) AS Stock_Out
            FROM    Stock
            WHERE   Direction='Out' AND Date_Time<=#2017/11/20  07:00:05#
            ) AS Balance
FROM        Stock
WHERE       Date_Time=#2017/11/20 07:00:05#
```